# Dataframe join on multiple IDs

Tags: julia

I'm trying to do a database style merge with at least two IDs using data-frame types:

```
merged_df = join(df1, df2, on = (:ID1 :ID2), kind = :outer)
```

This does not seem to be allowed in `base.join`.

I can make this work with some kind of verbose function, but I want to see if there's a cleaner way?

Comment: One solution (to my own problem) is to create a unique ID from the two IDs. ID_unique = ID1*ID2 and then merge with this ID. Still, it would be nice to have the ability to merge on multiple IDs as base functionality.

Comment: This seems like a good feature request over at [DataFrames.jl](https://github.com/JuliaStats/DataFrames.jl).  It seems like any answer here could easily become a pull request to officially implement the functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to ARM, it looks like this is close, but the actual syntax is:

```
merged_df = join(df1, df2, on = [[:ID1, :ID2]], kind = :outer)
```

I was getting an error when using your method

Answer (score 5):

```
merged_df = join(df1, df2, on = [:ID1, :ID2], kind = :outer)
```

DataFrames is awesome, but there's a lot of useful stuff that's not documented...  There's a few things I've been meaning to add to the documentation in the joins and split-apply-combine sections.

Comment: Plus one (+1) for added documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I receive an error here:                          names = DataFrame(ID = [1, 2], Name = ["John Doe", "Jane Doe"])
jobs = DataFrame(ID = [1, 2], Job = ["Lawyer", "Doctor"]) merge_df = join(names, jobs, on = [:ID :Job], kind = :inner)                                                         ERROR: type: typeassert: expected Union(Array{Symbol,1},Symbol), got Array{Symbol,2}

Comment: You're right -- I missed a comma when typing it in on my phone above.  It's now corrected.